# knockout JS bind to properties of object

Tags: javascript, html, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a need to bind some HTML to an object, but my issue is that I don't know the properties of the object at development time.

I have a `selectedItem` property in my main view model which I have bound to a section in my HTML:

```
<div data-bind="with: selectedItem">

</div>
```

Now I want to generate a table based on the property name and property values:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: [WHAT DO I PUT HERE?]">
    <label class="control-label"><span data-bind="text: [OR HERE?]" /></label>
</div>
```

I have really no idea how to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Also, just slightly extending this, I would like to handle the properties of the bound object differently, such as, if the property is just a primitive type, just output it, but if its another object/array, then handle it specially.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ2At/) is a working example using *computed observable* to select at runtime the data to show. Dynamically selected [templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) are also used to render the data according to the type of data to render (array or scalar).

Comment: This is a good start, but I fail to see exactly how this will give me access to the properties of the viewmodel that I dont know at design time. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure. Property "selected" contains the name of the property to select in the viewmodel (can be changed at runtime). Changing this value (observable) will trigger the update of property "data" (computed observable). This last property dynamically selects (see _self[selection]_) the data (list1 or item1) to render using the corresponding template. Hope this clarifies the example.

Comment: Ah, I see what you have done, thanks. But perhaps I am miss-understanding your thoughts, or perhaps I have not described the issue well enough. I the Model class has X properties (in your case 2 but mine has around 20), I want to list all of the properties and choose a template based on the type of that property. In your example, you have hard coded the properties in the select list, where as I wont know them ... does that make sense?

Comment: The select list is just there for the example. You can perfectly change the value of the property _selected_ by another mean. I made the example with 2 properties but you can have many. To select the right property to show, just put its name in the _selected_ property and the template will be automatically selected based on the type. In your case, how are you going to select the property to show ?

Comment: I want to show all properties of the bound model, only I dont know what the properties will be. So the foreach needs to bind to 'something', is there a property/method/utility in KO that you can call to get all properties of a model?

Comment: I think I understand you now. Is [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ2At/4/) what you were looking for ?

Comment: That looks very good!! Let me have a play and I will get back to you :)

Answer (score 13):

If anyone else is looking to bind a simple object's properties. You can do it like this...

```
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: arrayOfObjects">
        <tr data-bind="foreach: Object.keys($data)">
            <td data-bind="text: $parent[$data]"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

note: object.keys is not supported in older browsers, but you can use this to add backwards compatability http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/10/a-safer-object-keys-compatibility-implementation